# How to make an action happen if a checkbox is cheked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is what I want to do: I have a form on which I have a checkbox. When that checkbox is checked I want some additional fields to show and when it is not checked I want those fields not to show. Also after the form is submitted and there is some kind of error (for example the person has not confirmed that they are not a robot) I want the checkbox to remain checked if it was previously checked (and of course the additional fields still to be showed if it is checked).

I tried a couple of different approaches:

1. Using data-toggle
2. Using a JavaScript on click function of the checkbox
3. Using jQuery prop method
4. Using jQuery :checked selector

(Reference for 3. and 4. https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-check-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not-using-jquery.php)

An occurring problem with all of the methods was that after submitting the form with errors then the additional fields would not be shown even though the checkbox was checked.

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="additionalFields" class="checkbox-inline ml-1 mb-0">Show additonal fields</label>
            <input class="align-middle" type="checkbox" name="additionalFields" value="additionalFields" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fields" <?php if (isset($_POST['additonalFields'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group collapse in row" id="fields">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="form-control-label ml-1 mb-xs-form" for="fieldOne">Field 1:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fieldOne" name="fieldOne" maxlength="100" placeholder="Field 1"
                    <?php
                    if ($_POST && ($suspect || $errors || !($response->success))) {
                        echo 'value="' . htmlentities($fieldOne) . '"';
                    }
                    ?>>
                </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="form-control-label ml-1 mt-3 mt-sm-0" for="fieldTwo">Field 2</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fieldTwo" name="fieldTwo" maxlength="100" placeholder="Field 2"
                    <?php
                    if ($_POST && ($suspect || $errors || !($response->success))) {
                        echo 'value="' . htmlentities($fieldTwo) . '"';
                    }
                    ?>>
            </div>
        </div><!-- form-group -->
```

The above code is using data-toggle. When using JavaScript or jQuery I was using display: none; and display: flex; to show and hide the additional fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on html reloading, you need manually predefined what js event did if you click the checkbox. 
if you mean using data-toggle is using bootstrap accordion, then you need to add class 'show' to event data target to make that extra input field showed. 
so try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="additionalFields" class="checkbox-inline ml-1 mb-0">Show additonal fields</label>
    <input class="align-middle" type="checkbox" name="additionalFields" value="additionalFields" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fields" <?php if (isset($_POST['additonalFields'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
</div>

<div class="form-group collapse in row <?php if (isset($_POST['additonalFields'])) echo 'show'; ?>" id="fields">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="form-control-label ml-1 mb-xs-form" for="fieldOne">Field 1:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fieldOne" name="fieldOne" maxlength="100" placeholder="Field 1"
    <?php
        if ($_POST && ($suspect || $errors || !($response->success))) {
            echo 'value="' . htmlentities($fieldOne) . '"';
        }
    ?>>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="form-control-label ml-1 mt-3 mt-sm-0" for="fieldTwo">Field 2</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fieldTwo" name="fieldTwo" maxlength="100" placeholder="Field 2"
    <?php
        if ($_POST && ($suspect || $errors || !($response->success))) {
            echo 'value="' . htmlentities($fieldTwo) . '"';
        }
    ?>>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any jQuery but I assume you mean

```
$(function() {
  $("[name=additionalFields]").on("change",function() {
    $($(this).data("target")).toggle(this.checked);
  }).trigger("change"); // initialise on load
})
```